# Lenovo Tablet A1 disable screen lock

Tags: lock-screens, customization, lenovo-ideapad-tablet-a1

I have a Lenovo Tablet A1 and don't know how to configure the screen settings as I would like them. I want that after a certain timeout the screen dims, and/or goes black, but doesn't actually lock.

That is, right now if I choose a screen timeout the thing locks and I have to press the top power button and drag an icon across the screen -- extremely inconvenient.

I have disabled Screen Lock, but it doesn't change this aspect. I also installed No Lock, but it doesn't work on this device. So far my only half-success is to disable the screen timeout, but then it runs at maximum brightness the entire time.

I have checked many questions, and done searches, for disabling screen lock. Apparently none of these work on the Lenovo Tablet.

Answer (score 0):

[No Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock) works for me on my Lenovo A1!